# What is XPRS basic gate on IBM 'peekskill' system?

Tags: universal-gates

I have checked IBM 'peekskill' system and it has basic gates defined as: 
CX, ID, RZ, SX, X, **XPRS.**

It is the only one IBM system that has **XPRS** gate on its list.

Does anyone knows what kind of gate **XPRS** is?

Other 'peekskill' system properties:

- 27 qubits
- Processor type: Falcon r8
- Version: 2.1.0

Comment: It's an alternate implementation of a standard gate. If it makes it to widely-available systems, I think it would just be as an improved replacement for that standard gate.

Comment: Ok, so in this case is this an alternative to 'X' gate?